# html served from express app on azure is not gzipped

Tags: azure, express, azure-web-app-service, angular-universal

I'm trying to deploy an Angular Universal application to an Azure WebApp running on a Linux service plan. Even tho my browser indicates that it accepts gzip, the server does not encode the response with gzip.

Take for example this URL: https://msp-navigator-dev.azurewebsites.net/assets/logo-mspn.png

No content-encoding.

This file is served by an express server proxying the requested filename from disk. I'm not sure if Azure is misconfigured, or NodeJS, or the webserver or Express JS.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable compression in Express using the `compression` package ([npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression)).

```sh
npm install compression --save
```

And in your code:

```js
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(compression());
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! It feels a bit weird that this isn't enabled by default and that I couldn't find anything about it online...